# How to have edited task update local storage?

Tags: javascript

I am almost done with my to-do app, what is left is to do the local storage for the completed list and edited task.

The local storage I have done for when the task is added and removed. But I am not sure how to do the local storage for when the task is set to complete and when the task has been edited.

HTML

```
<div class="form">
  <input class="user-input" type="text">
  <input class="date" type="date">
  <input class="time" type="time">
  <button onclick="addTask()" class="add" id="add">+</button>
</div>

<div class="list"></div>
```

JS

```
//local storage key
const STORAGE_KEY = "tasks-storage-key";

// variables object
const el = {
  form: document.querySelector(".form"),
  input: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
  list: document.querySelector(".list"),
  date: document.querySelector(".date"),
  time: document.querySelector(".time"),
};

const updateEl = {
  formUpdate: document.querySelector(".form-update"),
  inputUpdate: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
  modal: document.querySelector(".modal"),
  dateUpdate: document.querySelector(".date-update"),
  timeUpdate: document.querySelector(".time-update"),
};

//Create ID

const createId = () =>
  `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}${new Date().getTime()}`;

//variable of empty array that gets new task
let taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) ?? "[]");

renderList();

function makeNewTask() {
  const data = {
    id: createId(),
    taskNew: el.input.value,
    taskDate: el.date.value,
    taskTime: el.time.value,
  };

  return data;
}

function updateTask() {
  const dataUpdate = {
    id: createId(),
    inputUpdate: updateEl.inputUpdate.value,
    dateUpdate: updateEl.dateUpdate.value,
    timeUpdate: updateEl.timeUpdate.value,
  };

  return dataUpdate;
}


function renderList() {
  // This resets the list innerHTML to the new list
  el.list.innerHTML = taskList.map(function (data) {
    return `<div class="task">
            <div class="task-content">
                <div class="task" data-id="${data.id}">
                <input class="new-task-created" value="${data.taskNew}" readonly></input>
                <input class="due-date" type="date" value="${data.taskDate}" readonly></input>
                <input class="due-time" type="time" value="${data.taskTime}" readonly></input>
                
            </div>
    
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <button onclick="editItem(event)" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
                <button onclick="deleteItem(event)" class="delete" data-id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
                <button onclick="completeItem(event)" class="complete" data-id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
            
        </div>`;
  })
  el.input.value = "";

  
}

//event listner that listens for add button.
function addTask() {
  taskList.push(makeNewTask());
  // store the list on localstorage because data changed
  storeList();
  // render list again because you've added a new entry
  renderList();
  
}

//function that removes task from array with delete button.
function deleteItem(event) {
  taskList.splice(taskList.indexOf(event.target.dataset.id), 1);

  // store the list on localstorage because data changed
  storeList();
  // render list again because entry was removed
  renderList();
}

//function that stores task list.
function storeList() {
  window.localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(taskList));
}

//function that that edits tasks with date and time.
function editItem(event) {

const editEl = event.target.closest(".task");
let taskUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".new-task-created");
let dateUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".due-date");
let timeUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".due-time");
let editbtn = editEl.querySelector(".edit");

if (editbtn.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == "edit"){
  taskUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
  dateUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
  timeUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
  taskUpdate.focus();

  editbtn.innerHTML = "Save";
}
else{
  taskUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
  dateUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
  timeUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
  editbtn.innerHTML = "Edit";
}

}

//function that that completes task.
function completeItem(event) {
  const element = event.target.closest(".task-content");
  let taskItem = element.querySelector(".new-task-created");
  let dateItem = element.querySelector(".due-date");
  let timeItem = element.querySelector(".due-time");
  // style..
  taskItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  dateItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  timeItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}
```

I have added a screenshot of the section of the code I am focusing on, I just put the entire code so you can see the flow.

[image]

Comment: Does editItem have any effect on the taskList?  I don't see it.  Same for completeItem.  Those both look like they change the dom only.

Comment: no I do not think it does, so that is what needs to be done, it needs to effect the array.

Comment: yes. think of the array as informing values in the dom, and dom events as changing the array.  put every kind of change to the array (add/remove/or change an item) in a function that also writes it to storage

Comment: okay, I am not sure how I can achieve that as it currently stands

Comment: I don't understand the following. Why are you creating a new `id` in the `updateTask()` function? Wouldn't you just modify the contents and last modification date/time?

Comment: @Sheldon - the input that gets rendered with each new task will produce change events as user types.  Listen to those changes, get the event.target.id to identify the task being edited, update the array and store.  Same idea for the completed button: give it a click listener, in that handler identify the id, update the array and store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here in some changes in your js file look into it.

1. in `editItem` function on behalf of `i` we change value in taskList.
2. in `completeItem` function on behalf of `i` we add one more prop in object `textDecoration: true` and in `renderList` function we use prop to add style.
3. pass index `i` to each button action in function like editItem, deleteItem, completeItem .

```js
//local storage key
const STORAGE_KEY = "tasks-storage-key";

// variables object
const el = {
    form: document.querySelector(".form"),
    input: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
    list: document.querySelector(".list"),
    date: document.querySelector(".date"),
    time: document.querySelector(".time"),
};

const updateEl = {
    formUpdate: document.querySelector(".form-update"),
    inputUpdate: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
    modal: document.querySelector(".modal"),
    dateUpdate: document.querySelector(".date-update"),
    timeUpdate: document.querySelector(".time-update"),
};

//Create ID

const createId = () =>
    `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}${new Date().getTime()}`;

//variable of empty array that gets new task
let taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) ?? "[]");

renderList();

function makeNewTask() {
    const data = {
        id: createId(),
        taskNew: el.input.value,
        taskDate: el.date.value,
        taskTime: el.time.value,
    };

    return data;
}

function updateTask() {
    const dataUpdate = {
        id: createId(),
        inputUpdate: updateEl.inputUpdate.value,
        dateUpdate: updateEl.dateUpdate.value,
        timeUpdate: updateEl.timeUpdate.value,
    };

    return dataUpdate;
}


function renderList() {
    // This resets the list innerHTML to the new list
    // <input class="new-task-created" value="${data.taskNew}" readonly style="text-decoration: 'line-through'"></input>
    el.list.innerHTML = taskList.map(function (data, i) {
        return `<div class="task">
            <div class="task-content">
                <div class="task" data-id="${data.id}" >
                <input class="new-task-created" value="${data.taskNew}" readonly style="${data.textDecoration ? 'text-decoration: line-through': ''}"></input>
                <input class="due-date" type="date" value="${data.taskDate}" readonly></input>
                <input class="due-time" type="time" value="${data.taskTime}" readonly></input>
                
            </div>
    
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <button onclick="editItem(event, ${i})" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
                <button onclick="deleteItem(event, ${i})" class="delete" data-id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
                <button onclick="completeItem(event, ${i})" class="complete" data-id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
            
        </div>`;
    })
    el.input.value = "";


}

//event listner that listens for add button.
function addTask() {
    taskList.push(makeNewTask());
    // store the list on localstorage because data changed
    storeList();
    // render list again because you've added a new entry
    renderList();

}

//function that removes task from array with delete button.
function deleteItem(event, i) {
    taskList.splice(i, 1);

    // store the list on localstorage because data changed
    storeList();
    // render list again because entry was removed
    renderList();
}

//function that stores task list.
function storeList() {
    window.localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(taskList));
}

//function that that edits tasks with date and time.
function editItem(event, i) {

    const editEl = event.target.closest(".task");
    let taskUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".new-task-created");
    let dateUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".due-date");
    let timeUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".due-time");
    let editbtn = editEl.querySelector(".edit");

    if (editbtn.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == "edit") {
        taskUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
        dateUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
        timeUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
        taskUpdate.focus();

        editbtn.innerHTML = "Save";
    }
    else {
        taskUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
        dateUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
        timeUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
        editbtn.innerHTML = "Edit";
        taskList[i] = {
            id: taskList[i].id,
            taskNew: taskUpdate.value,
            taskDate: dateUpdate.value,
            taskTime: timeUpdate.value
        }
        // store the list on localstorage because data changed
        storeList();
        // render list again because you've added a new entry
        renderList();
    }
}

//function that that completes task.
function completeItem(event, i) {
    const element = event.target.closest(".task-content");
    let taskItem = element.querySelector(".new-task-created");
    let dateItem = element.querySelector(".due-date");
    let timeItem = element.querySelector(".due-time");
    // style..
    taskItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    dateItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    timeItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";

    taskList[i] = {
        ...taskList[i],
        textDecoration: true
    }
    console.log('taskList', taskList)
    // store the list on localstorage because data changed
    storeList();
    // render list again because you've added a new entry
    renderList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For edited tasks I would first modify the `updateTask()` function so that it uses the *same* id as the originally created task:

```js
//...

  const taskData = {
    id: createId(),
    completed: false, // added
    contents: el.input.value,
    date: el.date.value,
    time: el.time.value,
  };

//...
```

You can modify the contents and the date/time to keep track of the last time it was modified. From there, you would do the simply call `storeList()` and `renderList()` to save to local storage and update the view.

For completed tasks I would either add a boolean property in the task data (something like `completed`) or a completion date (initially set to zero or null). From there you simply update and check for that value. And as for saving to local storage you would do the same: call `storeList()` and `renderList()`.